# How do you display a custom message with CefSharp when JavaScript handles OnBeforeUnload?

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I have implemented my own class for IJsDialogHandler for a **WinForms** desktop app. I want to display a custom dialog instead of the default dialog. The example from CefSharp GitHub site just says to return true to handle it myself, but that doesn't show me how to display my own dialog.

How do I display my dialog?

Do I need to also implement a LifeSpanHandler? I've seen some articles using it to know the browser is closing.

Comment: `return true`, display your dialog on the `UI thread` and execute the `callback` when your dialog has been closed. The implementation detail will depend on if you are using `WPF` or `WinForms`. You should have no problem finding examples of showing a dialog in either.

Comment: `IWebBrowser` can be cast to `ChromiumWebBrowser` and access the `UI Thread`.

Comment: I have been struggling to find working examples of a custom js dialog. If you have seen any, please post it here

Comment: UPDATE: this is for winforms

Comment: I can't close the question because of comments. @amaitland, if you create an answer then i'll mark it.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: I'm using `WinForms` and all I do is `MessageBox.Show("You must save!"); callback.Continue(false); return true;` and it's working. So, am I supposed to be on the UI thread if it's working?